# Google sheet formula or query

Tags: google-sheets

I need help with google sheet. I have a table where I evaluate the individual order of competitors, in the column "Individual score sum" and "Individual order".

I would also need to evaluate the order of the teams - the column "Team score sum" and "Team order". But count only the 2 or 3 best individual results in the team result according to the settings in the setting table.

[table link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BZF9rh9jz6d47CcL6w1p3CD5X1a22cg9RrYlY1IwlRw/edit#gid=0)

I can't create query or custom formula....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

***Team score sum***

```
=map(B2:B;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;if(countif(B2:Σ;Σ)=1;sum(sortn(filter(C:C;B:B=Σ);setting!B1;;1;0));))))
```

---

***Team order***

```
=map(E2:E;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;rank(Σ;tocol(E2:E;1);0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello again. I need some editing. Only count 2 or 3 minimum individual results in the team result according to the settings in the settings table. So in cell E2 the value should be 6 and so on. Any ideas please?

Comment: Just replace the `0` in this part of the formula here (`setting!B1;;1;0`) with `1`.  eventually it should be `setting!B1;;1;1`